# Reading from Kinesis stream with more than 1 shard in Spark Streaming

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, spark-streaming, sharding, amazon-kinesis-kpl

Getting following error:

`com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ShutdownException: Can't update checkpoint - instance doesn't hold the lease for this shard`

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Sounds like a Kinesis issue https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/108

Answer (score 0):

It seems like and kinesis issue. For debugging reason, you can enable logging for `LeaseManager`. There are some additional messages that should indicate the state of the checkpoint request. An important thing to take into consideration is `failoverTimeMillis`. You could try to increase the value of `failoverTimeMillis` this could help to avoid the following issue. More detailed explanation is in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-kinesis-connectors/issues/10#issuecomment-54921589).

> The root cause of this issue is that sometimes a KCL Worker loses a
> lease and then reacquires a new lease on a particular shard before
> discarding the old lease for that shard, it then continues to hold the
> old lease which still holds the old concurrency token. The mismatched
> concurrency token prevents checkpointing but the Worker never discards
> the lease because the lease cleanup logic only compares the shard-id.

> one way to alleviate the impact of this issue is to increase the
> failoverTimeMillis which is set to 1000ms by default in the connector
> library. Increasing the failoverTimeMillis will reduce the chance of a
> Worker losing and then immediately reacquiring its own lease.